# Difficulty solving $4x^2y^3y''=x^2-y^4$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> Solve $4x^2y^3y''=x^2-y^4.$

I was trying to reduce the order of this nonlinear ODE or to transform it into a linear ODE, but I couldn't come up with a suitable substitution.

I considered

\begin{aligned}(y^4)''&=(4y^3y')'\\&=12y^2(y')^2+4y^3y''\\\implies 4y^3y''&=(y^4)''-12y^2(y')^2\\\implies 4x^2y^3y''&=x^2(y^4)''-12x^2y^2(y')^2\\&= x^2(y^4)''-3(x^2\cdot 4y^2\cdot (y')^2)\\&=x^2(y^4)''-3(x\cdot 2yy')^2\\&=x^2(y^4)''-3(x(y^2)')^2\end{aligned} on the LHS. If I took $u:=y^2,$
I would get $$x^2(u^2)''-3(xu')^2=x^2-u^2,$$

but that situation doesn't seem any better than the initial one.

Is it possible to transform the given ODE into a linear one (not necessarily with constant coefficients)?

I assume it should be possible as I found it in old materials which don't cover anything beyond linear equations and Riccati's equation, which we transformed into linear.

However, I would appreciate any working method suggested.

Comment: FWIW, Mathematica can solve this and returns the solution,$$y(x)=\frac1{2\sqrt{c_1}} \sqrt x \sqrt{1+4{c_1}^2{c_2}^2-8{c_1}^2c_2 \ln(x)+4{c_1}^2\ln^2(x)}$$

Comment: Thank you! I also tried to look for the solution in the form $y(x)=f(x)\sqrt x$ so as to factor out $x^2$ on the RHS, but to no avail.

Comment: Probably a typo $4x^2y^3y'=x^2−y^4$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your equation is reducible to a linear differential equation. Rearranging we have
\begin{align}
y''+\frac{1}{4x^2}y=\frac{1}{4y^{3}},
\end{align}
which is an Ermakov differential equation, interestingly Wolfram Alpha cannot solve this. Let $w(x)$ be a nontrivial solution to the equation $4x^2w''+w=0$ (which you will solve) then the transformation $\xi=\smallint\mathrm dx/w^2$, $z=y/w$ gives that $y''_{xx}=w^{-3}z''{\xi\xi}+w''_{xx}z$, and so
\begin{align}
w^{-3}\left(z''_{\xi\xi}-\frac{1}{4}z^{-3}\right)+{\left(w''_{xx}+\frac{1}{4x^2}w\right)}z=0\quad\longrightarrow\quad 
z''_{\xi\xi}=\frac{1}{4}z^{-3}.
\end{align}
The latter of which can be integrated twice to yield
\begin{align}
C_1 z^2&=\frac{1}{4}+(C_2+C_1\xi)^2,\\\\
C_1y^2&=w^2\left(\frac14+\left(C_2+C_1\int\frac{\mathrm dx}{w^2}\right)^2\right).
\end{align}
Leaving our linear equation to solve... Can you take it from there?

Comment: Thank you! I'll proceed.